# How to send the tracing output to a file in the file system?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, trace

I have added the following code to my web.config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4" >
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="d:\debugging.txt" />
        <remove name="Default"></remove>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

And I have written this line for sending trace output:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(sID + " tracing id");
```

But, I can not see any "debugging.txt" file created on my d: drive and there is no trace output.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: For files, you need to have `autoflush="true"`.

Comment: Yes, after making autoflush="true", the trace output is coming in the target file, but from the line: HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write(sID + " tracing id"); not from the System.Diagnostics.Trace. And if I remove the writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" attribute from System.Web configSection then HttpContext trace also not works which is obvious.

Comment: ASP.NET displays trace messages whenever tracing is enabled for a page. (`trace.axd TraceViewer`).
To route Trace messages to an ASP.NET Web page, you must add a `WebPageTraceListener` object.

To view the ASP.NET and System.Diagnostics trace messages in a context outside an ASP.NET page, use a `TextWriterTraceListener` object to write the trace messages to a file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trace to a directory that the ASP.NET service has write permission on.

What I like to do is just leave the default listener and run TechNet DebugView, which has the option of saving or logging to a file.

Comment: I have configured a folder to have full control for Asp.Net machine account, now the file is created, but it is empty and does not contain any trace output. I have Trace="True" on my page and I can see the tracing output on my page in the browser.

Comment: Yes, after making autoflush="true", the trace output is coming in the target file, but from the line: HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write(sID + " tracing id"); not from the System.Diagnostics.Trace. And if I remove the writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" attribute from System.Web configSection then HttpContext trace also not works which is obvious.

Comment: The trace symbol must be defined, if it is not defined than the tracing output from the HttpContext.Current.Trace would also not have been written to the file.

Comment: I believe this has all the information you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx

Comment: ***TechNet DebugView*** not valid if I cannot access to _production environment_